# Вывод данных из DB на Django 3.0

Tags: база-данных, django, requests, view

Проблема заключается в том, что когда я перехожу по ссылке id, чтобы открыть статью к примеку home/learn/1 у меня появляется ошибка 404, хотя статья есть в DB. Подскажите пожалуйста, что надо сделать.

**Raised by: articles.views.home_checklist***

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.template import RequestContext
from . models  import *

def learn(request):
    learn = Learn.objects.order_by('-learn_pub_date')
    return render(request, "post/learn.html", {'learn':learn})

def learn_checklist(request, learn_id):
    try:
        learn_cl = Learn.objects.get(id = learn_id)
    except:
        raise Http404("Статья не найдена!!!")
    return render(request, 'list.html', {'learn_cl':learn_cl})
```

Urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

app_name = 'articles'
urlpatterns = [
    path('home/learn/', views.learn, name='learn'),
    path('home/learn/<int:learn_id>/', views.learn_checklist, name='learn_checklist'),
]
```

Learn.html - здесь выводятся весь список статей

```
{% if learn %}
{% for z in learn %}
<div class="container mx-auto p-3">
  <div class="grid grid-flow-auto grid-rows-max">
    <div class="col-auto text-center justify-center">
      <h2>{{ z.learn_title }} | {{z.learn_pub_date}}</h2>
      <br>
      <img src="{{ z.learn_image.url }}" class="img-fluid"/>
      <br>
      <a href="{% url 'articles:learn_checklist' z.id %}" class="btn btn-danger">Read next</a>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
```

List.html - это страница самой статьи

```
{% if learn_cl %}
<div class="container mx-auto p-3">
  <div class="grid grid-flow-auto grid-rows-max">
    <div class="col-auto text-center justify-center">
      <h2><em>{{ learn_cl.learn_title }}|{{ learn_cl.learn_pub_date }}</em></h2>
      <br>
      <img src="{{ learn_cl.learn_image.url }}" class="img-fluid">
      <br>
      <p>{{ learn_cl.learn_text }}</p>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

**Good luck for that :)**

Comment: Уберите try, и попробуйте без него. Вы же не смотрите, какая ошибка

Comment: Спасибо, в raise я вывожу ошибки

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что я использовал learn_id в другой view def и была проблема с переадресацией в никуда